# How retain the Hidden Field value after the page postback?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a hidden filed

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="hdnCFIV" Value="0" runat="server" />
```

I am changing the hidden filed value to 1 on a button click

```
hdnCFIV.Value = "1";
```

I am binding the datalist on page load

```
if(hdnCHIV.Value == "1")
```

But every time hdnCHIV.Value is showing 0 because my ascx page is reloading, if i'll keep the binding code in side the if(!IsPostBack) then other functionality will get affected.

How to retain the Hidden Field value once it is getting change from 0 to 1 on post back.
Is there any JavaScript or some other way? Please someone help me.

Comment: Why not bind it in the button click ?

Comment: are you loading ascx control on every post back??

Comment: @V4Vendetta: ok i am trying with that, let me check once

Comment: make sure youre binding your usercontrol on Page_Init not on Page_Load so viewstate is retained always.

Comment: than you need to save and load data for your control

Comment: @V4Vendetta: I am doing as you said and its working now, now i am not binding my datalist on page load.
thank you so much for ur response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that Load event occurs earlier than controls' events are being handled. So current workflow is like this:

1. ASP.NET parses the page, sets the `hdnCFIV.Value` property to 0.
2. `Page_Load` is called, `hdnCFIV.Value` equals 0 so the datalist binding is not performed.
3. Button click is handled, `hdnCFIV.Value` is set to 1.

To resolve this issue you need to perform datalist binding later, when `hdnCFIV.Value` is already set to 1. You can do this either in the same button click handler or in `Page_PreRender`.